# Table skipping divs

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to insert a table into a bootstrap modal but this simple code makes the table created destroy the modal internal content.

If i remove de table tags all goes back to normal.

The 'ABC' appear inside the modal correcly when opened but the table appear in the current page before opening the modal refered. I looked at the code result and it looks that it skipped the modal divs.

And this happens with custom bootstrap and normal tables, with or without content. Just putting the table causes the bug
Any solution?

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
         <label>ABC</label>
         <table></table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i didn't conclude where the problem came from but i got a solution for a work-around to this problem.

The solution is to build first the modal where the table will be and then use a script to insert the table in.

The code behind is like that:

> Step 1:  Build the modal and his body with a div to insert the table in

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
         <label>ABC</label>
         <div id="content_table"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Step 2:  Create a script or a function to build the table and then insert it in the div where you want the table to go (this js code can be done anywhere, just call it after the modal code)

```
<script>
   var content_user = document.getElementById("content_user");

   var htmlText = '' + 
   '<table class="table table-striped">' +
   '    <thead> '+
   '      <tr> '+
   '        <th>Table Header</th> '+
   '        <th>Table Header 2</th> '+
   '      </tr> '+
   '    </thead> '+
   '    <tbody> ';                                  

   htmlText += 
   '      <tr> '+
   '        <td>Content 1</td> '+
   '        <td>Content 2</td> '+
   '    </tr> ';

   htmlText += 
   '    </tbody> '+
   ' </table>';

   content_user.innerHTML = htmlText;
</script>
```